# how can I get my server application' public endpoint(ip, port) in a NAT network

Tags: c++, networking, boost-asio, nat

i start my server in a NAT envorment, and want to test it in public network,
how can i get its address? I am using boost::asio to write my app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know peer's public IP address, you need to have one server in public network (not behind any NATs), connect to the server and let the server sends client's IP address it sees back to the client. This site ( http://www.whatismyip.com/ ) shows your public address with this manner. So, your server needs to connect another server which resides in a public network without NAT invloved.

However, your server should not be in a NAT environment anyway as NAT normally blocks any incoming connections which are not initiated from inside peers. That means even though a client knows your server's public address, it won't be able to connect to the server behind NAT as NAT will block client's connection request.

Comment: it will be OK for client peer in nat, it is the same for server? any way, the sever is just a socket listener. i think NAT translated local addr to other ip and port for public, i just have no idea how to get the server's public addr.

Comment: NAT does not( cannnot ) care if your program is a server or a client. How would you tell difference to NAT?  Also, NAT is not just translating ip addresses. That's why there are may NAT traversal techniques. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal